# Parallel.For and ConcurrentBag giving unpredictable behavior

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am writing an application that, at some point, takes a mesh body and computes indices of adjacencies. To do this, I define an array of ConcurrentBag objects, then, in a parallel for loop I simply check some faces and if they have any adjacency, I add the index to said bag in the appropriate index. I.e.:

```
private bool parallelize = true;
private volatile ConcurrentBag<int>[] edge_adjacencies;
if (parallelize)
{
    ...
    Parallel.For(0, face_count, compute_adjacency_single);
    ...
}

private void compute_adjacency_single(int cur_idx)
{
    edge_adjacencies[cur_idx] = new ConcurrentBag<int>();
    foreach(int test_idx in SOME_TEST_SPACE)
    {
        if (test_idx != cur_idx)
        {
            bool edge_adj, vertex_adj;
            get_adjacency(cur_idx, test_idx, out edge_adj, out vertex_adj);
            if (edge_adj && !collection_contains(edge_adjacencies[cur_idx], test_idx))
            {
                edge_adjacencies[cur_idx].Add(test_idx);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I then index through the collections and check that each of then has size 3 (they should all have size exactly 3):

```
//DEBUGGING
for (int i = 0; i < face_count; i++)
{
    ConcurrentBag<int> cur = edge_adjacencies[i];
    if (cur.Count != 3) Console.WriteLine("incorrect:" + i);
}
//DEBUGGING
```

The result of this process is unpredictable: sometimes I get no output at all (all have size 3) and sometimes I get incorrect outputs:

Run 1:

```
incorrect:3791
incorrect:3792
incorrect:3829
incorrect:3837
incorrect:4476
```

Run 5:

```
incorrect:2855
incorrect:2856
incorrect:2879
incorrect:2880
```

Run 8:

```
incorrect:3271
```

Incorrect results are given every 9 runs or so.

For reference, when I run in serial it works perfectly every time.

I read on the MS documentation and it did say that the collections in System.Collections.Concurrent are supposed to be thread-safe, but it would seem this is not the case.

Why is this happening, and is there a nice way to prevent this?

Comment: Why even use a `ConcurrentBag` if there are never any two threads accessing the same index in the array? What concurrent access is there?

Comment: How is `collection_contains` implemented?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. This is a guess - but I don't think doing this `edge_adjacencies[cur_idx] = ..` in `compute_adjacency_single` is thread safe.

The `CuncurrentBag<int>` is very thread safe, but the *array* that holds the instances of them, are not.

I would use a  [ConcurrentDictonary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2?view=netframework-4.8) instead of the array.

Comment: I'll take a look and see if I can implement using a dictionary, although every thread accesses a unique element from that array...

Comment: It must be a collection type that is thread safe, a "normal" dictonary will have the same problem. 
The problem is not the uniqueness of `cur_idx`, but (I suspect) rather the implementation of array's index method.

Comment: If each thread accesses a different index in the array there should be no threading issues.

Comment: @Rotem It’s just not the same issue as you are talking about. 
Accessing a bag in the array - functions like a get-method. That get-method returns the bag at the specific index. That get-method is not thread safe.

Comment: That's exactly what Im talking about. Assuming no threads access the same index in the array, access is safe.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a jagged array just to be sure (or a flattened 1D array if you don't find it that hard to implement) but that's just my preference as I get the data more or less ordered by the index.

I think the problem is that there are race conditions when using `bool edge_adj, vertex_adj;`. Create an array or whatever thread-safe data-structure you like more and fill it with the `get_adjacency` function, so that you can access the booleans without the threads overwritting each other's values.

Comment: How would the threads overwrite each other's values if they never access the same array element?

Comment: @Rotem because there aren't arrays! The threads are trying to access at the same time the `bool edge_adj, vertex_adj;` variables

Comment: How is that possible? Those are **local** variables. They only exist within the thread-local `foreach` loop.

Comment: Because they are being passed by reference to the `get_adjacency` method, so the same address is being overwritten.

Comment: But the address is of a local variable. Its address is different for each thread. Possibly even in different iterations of the loop in each thread.

Comment: Wouldn't the non-locality of the `get_adjacency` method mess the thread-safety?

Comment: Not unless the code inside it is explicitly violating thread safety, but we don't see that code in the question. A method is not data, it can not inherently be thread unsafe.

Comment: If the method is doing IO as I think it is, then it's probable.